# Power BI embedded report - use new look with page navigation on the left

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I use the [Power BI JavaScript library](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) to embed Power BI reports into my web application. By default, embedded reports have the "old look" of the Power BI - the one where pages of the report are displayed as "tabs" in the bottom part of the embedded frame. Meanwhile, Power BI [introduced](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-look-for-power-bi-service/) a "new look" in 2019. In particular, report pages are now displayed to the left of the report content, and this is the feature that interests me the most.

Is it possible to customize the Power BI embed configuration in order to have the "new look" experience in the embedded report? In particular, is it possible to have the report pages on the left navigation bar, and not in the bottom part of the embedded frame?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible currently.

"The Power BI service (app.powerbi.com) has a new look" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/service-new-look-where-actions

The new look feature is only scoped in the Power BI service on PowerBI.com and not through embedding. You could submit this as an idea/request to be added to embedding here https://ideas.powerbi.com/